# Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': function (root)....upda...<omitted>... } could not be cloned

Tags: indexeddb, localforage, angular-akita

I am using Akita Statemanagement for Angular Application.And I have created two store with localForage configuration with driver as IndexedDB,name as Akita,StoreName as "AppDataStore".And Store key is the name of the store.

The following is the version,store configuration.

```
objectStore localforage configuration:
Store1:
---------------------------------------
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
@StoreConfig({ name: 'MyStore1' })
export class MyStore1 extends Store<MyStore1State> {
    constructor(private appConfig:AppConfig) {

        super(createInitialState(JSON.stringify(json)));
        localForage.config({
            driver: localForage.INDEXEDDB,
            name: 'Akita',
           storeName:'AppDataStore'
          });

        persistState({key:this.storeName,include:[this.storeName], storage: localForage });

    }
}

Store2:
---------------------------------------
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
@StoreConfig({ name: 'MyStore2' })
export class MyStore2 extends Store<MyStore2State> {
    constructor(private appConfig:AppConfig) {

        super(createInitialState(JSON.stringify(json)));
        localForage.config({
            driver: localForage.INDEXEDDB,
            name: 'Akita',
           storeName:'AppDataStore'
          });

        persistState({key:this.storeName,include:[this.storeName], storage: localForage });

    }
}
```

### package.json

```
{
"localforage": "^1.7.3",
"@datorama/akita": "^4.6.0"
}
```

While performing any update operation not able update in indexeddb and getting the following error

> ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore':
>   function (root) {
>           var _a;
>           return _a = {},
>               _a[(/** @type {?} */ (keyOrRoot))] = upda...... } could not be cloned.
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:222069:37
>       at createTransaction (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:221822:9)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:222053:13
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2815:26)
>       at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:79196:33)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2814:32)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2565:43)
>       at http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3299:34
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2848:31)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:79187:33)

Please any help.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are trying to store a function?

Comment: Actualy state contains object({}) but i was trying to update state object through arrayUpdate....after change working fine.

Comment: Does Akita persistState still use the serialize/deserialize options when using localforage?